# Wordpress 'sub-page'/'partial'?

Tags: php, wordpress

I haven't used wordpress at all before and I'm trying to reskin an existing wordpress site. All is going well, but in page.php I'd like to have a similar layout to this:

```
title
-------
A paragraph of text that varies depending on the category of the page
-------
The article
```

That paragraph is will be different depending on the category ID. Is there any stock way of doing this in wordpress? I was going to just make an API that grabs that section but if there's already a way to do this, that would be great.

Comment: @SankalpMishra Why is that important when the OP is asking about best practice? + there is an explanation of how the OP would approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the category settings page, there is a field which enables you to give each category a description. This form field would be perfect for your paragraph. The content can be retrieved by [category_description()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description).